# Convolution in time frequency domain

Tags: convolution, s-transform

I have a rectangular matrix S which is the amplitude of S-transform and a matrix G whose arrays are zero and one.
G and S have the same size. Each row corresponds to time ti and each column to frequency fj.
Now, I have to calculate the convolution of G*S in time frequency domain such the result should be the same size of S.
How can I do that?
Do you know any MATLAB function which does this calculation?
Thank you so much

Comment: Could you give more details on your matrices?

Comment: What's an "S-transform" ?

Comment: Does this help: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26035-joint-frequency-and-delay-correlation

Comment: This link explains the S-transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_transform. It look likes wavelet transform and with it you can evaluate the time-frequency distribution of a signal. It is in the form S(t,f) = S(x(t)), where x(t) is a one dimensional signal and you can calculate the S-transform amplitude S for each instant of time t and frequency.